# Verifiable Credential - Presentation request gives an Internal Server Error

Tags: azure-ad-verifiable-credentials

**Microsoft Entra, a new Home of Microsoft Verifiable Credential** is really new and nice feature. While I am playing around the items, I found an issue which I am not sure is an issue from my code rather Its more from the platform.

To give you little detail:

> - Company A: I have one Microsoft Verifiable Account to create the credentials for Company A employee.
> - Company B: I have one Microsoft Verifiable Account to verify (who likes to give a discount to those employees who are from Company A).

**Step 1:** using Company A, I have created the Verifiable Credential and It is stored in my Microsoft Authenticator App successfully.

**Step 2:** Coming to the next part of the story, Company B generates the presentation request where It likes to verify Company A employees' identity. I am able to create that presentation request and QR code for that as well.

**Issue comes:** Now, when I scan that presentation QR code using the authenticator app, It finds my stored crednetial is matching with this request. so, It gives me an option to share that credential against this presentation reuqest which is good and correct. But the moment I press "Share" it wait for a second and gives me an error message.

The error message is user friendly: Oops, failed to connect.
It seems there is a problem with one of our services connecting to your device. Check your network connection and try again.

But in technical detail, It says:

```
Error Code: internalServerError
Error Details: A generic error has occurred on the server.; Not Found; Not Found
TimeStamp: Dec1, 2022 10:02:48 AM EST
Request ID: 438395be97f20bbcc31511351121bbaa
Correlation ID: 3sg46/0ARha0zS/XHYKGfA.6.4
```

It also gives an option to see the track which is way long and can not be copy in mobile clipboard. But I took a part of that and that is below:

```
2022-11-30 17:49:33,560 INFO/Broker: [com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.result.MsalBrokerResultAdapter:authenticationResultFromBundle][2022-11-30 17:49:33 - thread_name: pool-27-thread-2, correlation_id: b27725eb-c6fc-4a0f-bdd5-dd5f3f74270b - Android 30] Broker Result returned from Bundle, constructing authentication result ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()@641 [pool-14-thread-1]
2022-11-30 17:49:33,562 INFO/App: MSAL acquire token silently success: com.microsoft.identity.client.AuthenticationResult@5709e74 MsalTokenRefreshManager$getTokenSilentlyAsync$4$1$onTaskCompleted$acquireTokenSilentParameters$1.onSuccess()@567 [main]
2022-11-30 17:49:33,563 INFO/Broker: [com.microsoft.identity.common.java.result.LocalAuthenticationResult][2022-11-30 17:49:33 - thread_name: pool-27-thread-2, correlation_id: b27725eb-c6fc-4a0f-bdd5-dd5f3f74270b - Android 30] Id Token type: IdToken ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()@641 [pool-14-thread-1]
2022-11-30 17:49:33,563 INFO/Broker: [com.microsoft.identity.common.java.result.LocalAuthenticationResult][2022-11-30 17:49:33 - thread_name: pool-27-thread-2, correlation_id: b27725eb-c6fc-4a0f-bdd5-dd5f3f74270b - Android 30] Constructing LocalAuthentication result, AccessTokenRecord null: false, AccountRecord null: false, RefreshTokenRecord null or empty: false, IdTokenRecord null: false ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()@641 [pool-14-thread-1]
2022-11-30 17:49:33,564 INFO/App: Token result: Success AadRemoteNgcAuthCheckUseCase$checkForAuth$2.invokeSuspend()@88 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-5]
2022-11-30 17:49:33,564 INFO/Broker: [CommandDispatcher:submitSilent][2022-11-30 17:49:33 - thread_name: pool-27-thread-2, correlation_id: b27725eb-c6fc-4a0f-bdd5-dd5f3f74270b - Android 30] Completed silent request as owner for correlation id : **b27725eb-c6fc-4a0f-bdd5-dd5f3f74270b, with the status : COMPLETED is cacheable : true ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()@641 [pool-14-thread-1]
2022-11-30 17:49:33,564 INFO/App: ListSessionsUseCase request with client request ID: 09871643-7561-4d9a-8e43-567c4d0480cb RemoteAuthenticationManager.listSessions()@201 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-5]
```

**Just to troubleshoot**:

1. I have tried to restart my phone.
2. Connected with wi-fi and data card.
3. I tried to check the previous Company A issuer Credential flow is still working and giving me the credential and all are working.

So, it is not an issue from my device and neither is the issue with authenticator connectivity issue from my side.

Answer (score 0):

I think your implementation is based on the [following Azure sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-verifiable-credentials-dotnet).

If so, please comment out the line on *VerifierController.cs* file under `PresentationCallback()` method which has a statement like `//payload = presentationResponse["issuers"].ToString()`. The data in the incoming request payload doesn't have `"issuers"`. Instead of commenting out, you can also use the following:

```
payload = presentationResponse["verifiedCredentialsData"][0]["issuer"];
```

Comment: Nope. I do not think that is the issue. because I am not getting the PresentationCallback called. I have a breakpoint but it did not get fit. I am getting an error in Mobile before it. Again steps like  Again steps are: I have a presentation request and I have an issuer card so, the Authenticator app finds that I have the card saved which can be used against presentation requests, It offers me to use that.     I click the shred button in Authenticator App and boom. I get an error. I do not get the breakpoint hit on the PresentationCallback function.

Answer (score 0):

we encountered an error that seems to be the same as the one you are encountering.
This was ultimately resolved by using ngrok and ensuring that the presentation_request_config.json was up to date with the configuration from our verified ID service and our new temporary ngrok URL for the `callback:url` setting.